# How do I save and load settings on the Xbox?

Tags: xna, c#, xbox360

I'm using XNA 4.0. How can I load and save settings when on the Xbox? And can I write to and read from files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will be able to read and write from any flat file (XML, JSON to name two), you can also use SQLite with XNA 4.0

Here are some [samples from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199073.aspx)

Comment: Awesome! That's just great!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `IsolatedStorage` for settings specific to a particular console (resolution, volume, etc.), and `StorageContainer` for save game data (that gamers should be able to back up & take with them).

`StorageContainer` data allows the player to select on which storage device to write the data, whereas `IsolatedStorage` writes on the same device where the game is, no questions asked.

For your game to successfully pass review on XBLIG, you'll need to ensure all cases work correctly (cancelling the device selection dialog, handling removal of a storage device, etc.)

Useful links:

- [Reading files in XNA 4.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20160104224055/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/12/09/reading-files-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)
- [How to show the device selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203920(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx)
- The ["evil checklist"](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/resources/help/peer_review_evil_checklist) which lists reasons for review failure. See test case 3 & 4.